# Nested router view not showing; view components are not mounted

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have `/your` route with a `/your/profile` nested route. When I go to `/your`, the text "Index" is rendered. When going the nested route (`/your/profile`), it doesn't show anything. Both the Index & Profile components are not even mounted.

I'm expecting to see the text "Index" & "Profile" (below it), as well as the alert text. But None are showing. I have followed the instruction as documented from the [official source](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html). Any idea what's causing the issue?

## router/index.js

```
import Your from "../views/your/Index.vue";
import Profile from "../views/your/Profile.vue";

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/your",
    name: "Your",
    component: Your,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/profile",
        component: Profile
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

## Index.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-container>
      <p>Index</p>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Your",
  mounted() {
    alert("Index Mounted");
  }
};
</script>
```

## Profile.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>Profile</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Profile",
  mounted() {
    alert("Profile Mounted");
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the / from children

Because this will be treated as root path

Look at vue docs

[vue docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html)